# Java: package cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I have this error while using a package class in another package.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Please post your code. There is no such thing like a **package class**.

Comment: give more details.  maybe include the compiler error message.

Comment: it appears you have a class called `package` which is not legal.

Comment: public class List extends  Mypackage.AList {}                        // and the error is: Mypackage cannot be solved as a type

Answer (score 2):

Based on my guess about your problem I suspect that you have something like this in your code:
`System.out.println(java.lang);`

Note that the parameter to the println method is the name of a package.  The java compiler gives the error "java.lang can not be resolved to a class" when you do this.

Comment: Sorry but it's not in java package. the code is:                             public class List extends Mypackage.AList {}                          // And the error is: Mypackage cannot be solved as a type

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the package statement of your class AList.
I guess if your package statement is something like `com.earth.europe.MyPackage`, then what you are trying to do wont work.
I suggest you instead import the class AList and just use as -

```
public class List extends AList {}
```

Also, I suppose List is not the actual classname you are using.

Comment: Yes i just take List as an example. Your solution work but why do i have this error if i put com.earth.europe.MyPackage.AList.